# How to expose a Model's collection in the ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm implementing MVVM for a class which represents recursively nested types.  For example:

```
class NestedType
{
    // Other properties here

    public Collection<NestedType> SubElements {get; set;}
}

class NestedTypeViewModel
{
    ObservableCollection<NestedType> ModelCollection { ??? }
}
```

How do I expose the items in the Model's collection in an observable way? (i.e., the View will be adding, creating, and modifying the subelements)  I assume I need the collection in the ViewModel to be `ObservableCollection<T>` but what about in the Model?  I could also make that an `ObservableCollection` and just directly expose it...

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should not have a setter on a property unless it calls `PropertyChanged` in it, with collections you normally make the `readonly` by providing a private backing field and only a public getter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly return the ObservableList from your model. WPF will take the reference of the Collection and registers to the CollectionChanged Event of the model collection.

```
class MyViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<NestedType> MyItems { return Model.Items; }
}
```

BUT, you will break what you are trying to achieve by using MVVM. A ViewModel should not expose a model, single or collection, otherwise your view could bind to a model which you should not do in MVVM.

Well MVVM is no religion and everyone implements certain parts differently. If this is no problem for you ... Go ahead and do it directly.

If you want a clean solution, you have multiple options to go from here. Just allowing a Manager to modify the collection of the model and create a corresponding view model or My favorit approach is to have an object that syncs model and viewmodel collection, by automatically wrap newly added models in a new view model and add this vm into the parent viewmodel list.

Comment: In contrast to your comment that exposing models for data binding "break"s MVVM, when defining a Model class, Miscrosoft has [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx): "The model classes typically provide property and collection change notification events through the INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyCollectionChanged interfaces. This allows them to be easily data bound in the view. Model classes that represent collections of objects typically derive from the ObservableCollection<T> class."

Comment: @RMart +1 because that is a great reference on MVVM.

Comment: Well thats why i said "everyone implements certain parts differently" there is no right or wrong. In my opinion it is better to wrap everything in a viewmodel and don't bind a model directly to the view. For example, a list of Models but you need a command on each item, the command should be a property in the viewmodel for the model, not in the model directly. But again, as long as you define your rules, constraints and goals you can implement MVVM however you like and need. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can live without separate `Model` entity as long as you don't need to pass different `Models` into `ViewModel`, so you can stick with `ViewModel` which represents an actual `Model` data.

I would recommend to expose it using private field under the hood along with `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
class NestedTypeViewModel 
{     
    private ObservableCollection<NestedType> dataItems; 

    public ObservableCollection<NestedType> DataItems
    {
       get
       { 
          return this.dataItems;
       }
       private set
       {
           this.dataItems = value;
           // here is should be OnPropertyChanged("DataItems") call
       }
    } 
}
```

**EDIT: answer to comments**

But if you already has such entity like Model - so try to inject in ViewModel by an Interface so Model and ViewModel at least would be decoupled

Comment: I appreciate the answer, unfortunately I do need a separate VM in this case for a couple reasons. 1)  The VM has a bunch of ICommands (not shown) to support interaction with the View (the example above is simplified to demonstrate the thrust of the question). 2) The Model is used in other projects at my company and I can't modify it to suit my VM needs.

Comment: I mean you do not ned a separate MODEL, but if you already has such entity - so try to inject in ViewModel by an Interface so Model and ViewModel at least would be decoupled